# drupal 8 commerce get product returns empty object

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-commerce

So i have created a few products and added some data to it:

[image]

In my custom route i am then trying to get all products out using the following code:

```
$products = \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product::loadMultiple();
$response['data'] = $products;
$response['method'] = 'GET';
return new JsonResponse($response);
```

However this returns the following reponse:

```
{"data":{"3":{},"6":{},"7":{}},"method":"GET"}
```

Can anyone tell me what ive done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON response is not encoding past the first level of depth. As far as I can tell, you cannot control that when using `new JsonResponse()`.

One solution is to build your own data structure and encode the JSON manually. This solution uses the serializer service: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191474/70331

In your case, something like this should encode the full entity structure.

```
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
...

$products = Product::loadMultiple([$ids]);

$response['data'] = $products;
$response['method'] = 'GET';

$serializer = \Drupal::service('serializer');
$jsonResponse = JsonResponse::fromJsonString($serializer->serialize($response, 'json'));
return $jsonResponse;
```

If using the 'serializer' it is best to provide that to the controller via dependency injection.